# How to change image file name in HTML code of different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

How to change image name in HTML code of different screen sizes?

for example I want do like

**if screen is max-width:1024**

```
<img src="sample400X400.jpg>
```

**and if screen is max-width:min-width:1900px**

```
<img src="sample800X800.jpg>
```

Is it possible

Comment: Purely with CSS? Currently it can't happen as far as I know. Maybe some options here: http://css-tricks.com/9838-techniques-for-context-specific-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS by using [media-queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/) or in JavaScript by detecting changes to the width of the viewport (`$(window).width();`).

You can detect the change in viewport width by listening for `onresize` events:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Dear negative voter, please tell me why so I can either improve my answer or remove it if it's incorrect.

Comment: How i can with css using media queries? as you wrote?

Comment: @JitendraVyas If you want a purely CSS and media query option, you should specify so in your question. This option answers if it is possible, but you didn't specify there were constraints.

Comment: Sorry I read the initial part as background images. You can't do it with media queries, unless you use the `content` property (not a good idea IMO). This project may help you though: https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JS script to do this :

```
img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = (document.body.offsetWidth < 1024) ? "sample400X400.jpg": "sample800X800.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

I have put a exemple on my server, you can look at this if you want (you need to resize and reload the page to see any change) http://frommelt.fr/img-size/